# Как автоматически выделить первую строку в NSTableView после загрузки данных?

Tags: macos

Внутри метода applicationDidFinishLaunching подгружаю данные, используя CoreData и пытаюсь выделить первую строку после загрузки:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  Persons = [self fetchPersons];
  [_tv_persons reloadData];

  if(Persons.count > 1)
  [_tv_persons selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[Persons count]-1] byExtendingSelection:YES];
}
```

Но, видимо, загрузка данных происходит в отдельном потоке и на момент попытки выделить нужную строку данные ещё не получены.

Подскажите, как с этим бороться? Костыли вроде таймера использовать не хочется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071503/how-to-tell-when-uitableview-has-completed-reloaddata)

Сразу после запуска перезагрузки таблицы `[_tv_persons reloadData];` добавляй в поток нужное действие

```
[_tv_persons reloadData];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(Persons.count > 1)
        [_tv_persons selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[Persons count]-1] byExtendingSelection:YES];
});
```